# По какой причине количество контейнеров может превысить максимальное количество?

Tags: java, многопоточность, синхронизация, семафоры

Может кто-нибудь подскажет, столкнулся с такой проблемой.

У меня есть потоки корабли, которые загружают и разгружают контейнеры на склад в порту. Количество контейнеров на складе конечное. Также есть конечное число пирсов и на каждом пирсе может обслуживаться только 1 корабль. Метод, выполняющие процесс загрузки и разгрузки залочен методами `lock.lock()` ,библиотеки concurrent, но при этом происходит ситуация, описанная ниже.

Т.е. каким-то образом происходит вхождение в if условие , которое проверяет чтобы количество контейнеров на складе после операции не превысило максимальное количество, а происходить должно следующее, если условие не выполняется, то поток засыпает.

[image]

Вот сам метод

```
 public void actionPier(DocOperation operation, int containerCount) {
    lock.lock();
    try {

        PierList pierList= PierList.getInstance();

        switch (operation) {

            case CONTAINER_UNLOAD:

                flag = true;
                while (flag) {

                    int currentAmountOfContainer = pierList.getCurrentAmountOfContainer().get();

                    if ((currentAmountOfContainer + containerCount) <= PierList.MAX_STORAGE_CAPACITY) {

                        System.out.println("Pier №" + pierNumber + " is busy: " + "Unloading " + containerCount +
                                " counteiners with ship... Stock has: " +
                                pierList.getCurrentAmountOfContainer() + " containers");

                        pierList.addCurrentAmountOfContainer(containerCount);

                        flag = false;
                       // isFree.signal();
                        lock.unlock();
                    } else {

                        System.out.println("Pier №" + pierNumber + " is busy: "+
                                "The stock hasn't counteiners for unloading. Wait.");

                        Thread rail = new Thread(new RailWay());
                        rail.setDaemon(true);
                        rail.start();
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(MAX_WAITING_TIME);
                    }
                }

                break;
            case CONTAINER_LOAD:

                flag = true;
                while (flag) {

                    int currentAmountOfContainer = pierList.getCurrentAmountOfContainer().get();

                    if (currentAmountOfContainer >= containerCount) {

                        System.out.println("Pier №" + pierNumber + " is busy: " + "Loading " + containerCount +
                                " counteiners in ship... Stock has: " +
                                pierList.getCurrentAmountOfContainer() + " containers");

                        pierList.decrementCurrentAmountOfContainer(containerCount);

                        flag = false;
                       // isFree.signal();
                        lock.unlock();
                    }
                    else {

                        System.out.println("Pier №" + pierNumber + " is busy: " +
                                "The stock hasn't counteiners for loading. Wait.");

                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(MAX_WAITING_TIME);

                    }
                }

                break;
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {

        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: На печать выводит непонятно что.

Comment: На скриншоте явно не то, что в коде. И избегайте скриншотов в вопросах без крайней необходимости (коей здесь нет).

Comment: Что-то ваш lock.unlock() слишко рано вызывается. Если flag это тоже разделяемы ресурс, то когда вы вышле из unlock другой поток может установить flag в true и ваши 2 потока будут крутится в цикле.